# Кот или кошка –/,

Tags: пунктуация

Можете сказать, как правильно?

Кот или кошка – определяется старым, народным способом.

Кот или кошка, определяется старым, народным способом.

P. S. Здесь *Кот или кошка* – подлежащие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь лучше поставить тире:

***Кот или кошка** – определяется старым, народным способо*м.

Предложение можно рассматривать как бессоюзное сложное (БСП) с инверсированной изъяснительной частью (кот или кошка).

В разговорной речи пауза может не подчеркиваться, и тогда допускается запятая.